# Vue - How to get document/window properties bound to a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

I would like to listen to all focus events on inputs accross my Vue application.
To get the currently focused input, I thought about binding the `document.activeElement` property to a computed property in my app component, but this is not reactive, **why** ?

Declaring the activeElement in the data is not reactive either.

Same thing for watchers !

The only way to get it working is by simply returning the value after a focus/blur event on the input itself, but that doesn't suit my needs here.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    activeElem: document.activeElement.tagName,
    realActiveElem: document.activeElement.tagName,
  },
  methods: {
    getActiveElem() {
      this.realActiveElem = document.activeElement.tagName;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    focused() {
      return document.activeElement.tagName;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeElem(val, oldVal) {
      console.log(val !== oldVal);
    },
    focused(val, oldVal) {
      console.log(val !== oldVal);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2 @focus="getActiveElem()">
    Data: {{activeElem}}
  </h2>
  <h2>
    Computed: {{focused}}
  </h2>
  <h2>
    From function to data: {{realActiveElem}}
  </h2>
  <input placeholder="Focus/Blur me" id="test" @focus="getActiveElem()" @blur="getActiveElem()" />
</div>
```

Is there any way to bind document or window properties as reactive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue can only react to changes made to data, not to the DOM. The change in document.activeElement is a DOM change.

You could use use an event to fire a method to update data. For example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    element: ""
  },
  created() {
    document.addEventListener("focusin", this.focusChanged);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    document.removeEventListener("focusin", this.focusChanged);
  },
  methods: {
    focusChanged(event) {
      this.element = event.target.tagName;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input id="mine">
  <p>{{ element }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Clean enough for me ! Thanks !